# prove that $ \ O(2) \ $ is diffeomorphic to $ \ S^1 \sqcup S^1 $

Tags: manifolds

Given  $ \ O(2) = \{A \in  M_{2 \times 2 } : A^TA = I_2 \ \} \ $

prove that $ \  O(2) \ $ is diffeomorphic to  $ \ S^1 \sqcup S^1 $

with $ \sqcup  \ $ the disjoint union and  $ \ S^1  \ $ the 1-sphere .

**Answer:**

**Is there any help ?**

Comment: no, $O(2)$ is one-dimensional

Comment: $O(2)$ is a 1-dim manifold.

Comment: "Since they are finite dimensional , there exists an Isomorphism between them" might be true for something like vector spaces, but not manifolds.

Answer (score 5):

> I know that $O(2)$ is a $2$-dimensional manifold.

No it isn't.

> Hence $S^1\sqcup S^1$ is a $2$-dimensional manifold.

No, no, no.

> Since they are finite dimensional , there exists an Isomorphism between them .

NO, STAHP.

Saying two spaces have the same number of dimensions does not imply they are isomorphic as groups - in fact, manifolds may not be groups at all! How can you say there exists an isomorphism when you haven't specified any group structure on $S^1\sqcup S^1$?

---

The Lie group $\mathrm{O}(2)$ is a **one**-dimensional manifold with two connected components. The component containing the identity matrix is the group $\mathrm{SO}(2)$ of all rotations of the plane. The other component contains all reflections across lines.

The space $S^1\sqcup S^1$ is a pair of disjoint circles, which is also evidently **one**-dimensional.

So your task is twofold: (a) find a nice bijection between rotations and points on the circle, (b) find a nice bijection between reflections across lines and points on the circle. For the latter, it may help to know why the real projective line is diffeomorphic to a circle, $\mathbb{RP}^1\simeq S^1$. Then check the bijections are diffeomorphisms.